# Box-shadow and border styles conflicting in Wordpress CSS

Tags: wordpress, css

I'm having trouble applying an outline and drop shadow to some images in a Wordpress widget.
The '2017' theme adds some related rules which conflict with mine and cause the image to appear with a white vertical line in place of the border, which appears to crop the right of the image, as well as the top and bottom border and drop shadow. If I remove these rules in the Chrome DevTools the problem is fixed.
I can't simply remove those rules from the theme as I'm doing this as part of a plugin which users will add to their own sites, so I'd like to update my css to fix the problem without modifying the underlying theme.
Is there a way to do this?

The css in the theme (that I can delete in Chrome DevTools to fix) is:

```
/* Fixes linked images */
.entry-content a img,
.widget a img {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 8px #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 8px #fff;
}
```

I'm trying to override this in the plugin style sheet with:

```
.entry-content a img,
.widget a img {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

and adding this as inline CSS to the 'img' tag:

```
style="border:3px solid orange; box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 1px #333; -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 1px #333;"
```

I've also tried adding this inline CSS to the 'a' tag which encloses the images:

```
style="-webkit-box-shadow: none;  -moz-box-shadow: none;  box-shadow: none;"
```

This has no effect however.

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: You can try to add !important behind the CSS rule. Putting the CSS inside the child theme should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't fix it, I've now solved the issue though and added an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help!
It turned out though that the CSS in the theme was being applied to an image next to the one I was trying to apply the border and shadow to, so I had to override the CSS in that image, in addition to the one I was trying to modify.

So I had to apply this to the other image as well as retaining it in the 'a' tags:

```
style="-webkit-box-shadow: none;  -moz-box-shadow: none;  box-shadow: none;"
```

Comment: the style attribute will override the values in the external stylesheet, as it is the last declared, which is what I said in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The rules of CSS (**Cascading** style sheets) are as follows:

- a more specifically defined rule will override a general one (e.g. a rule specified for `div.entry-content` will override a rule specified for `.entry-content`)

  - the last declaration overrides all the others (e.g. an inline style in the style attribute will override something declared in the external style sheet) - use this rule sparingly as it gets confusing
  - adding `!important` to your property will override other declarations - use this rule sparingly as it gets confusing

so the answer is either:

```
div.entry-content a img,
div.widget a img {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

OR:

```
.entry-content a img,
.widget a img {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't fix it, please see the solution I've added.

Comment: but my answer does answer the actual question that you asked